# Custom element two-way binding update without triggering valueChange

Tags: javascript, aurelia

I have a situation here, the `valueChanged` gets called even if I change the bindable property `value` internally within custom element. How do I send the updated value back to viewModel from custom element without triggering `valueChanged` for that bindable value.

is there a way to supress this? or I have to use internal tracking if this is called from internal code or coming from view?

Comment: If the value in the custom element is changed, do you still want to update the view model variable?

Comment: let me clear this little bit. I do want to update the viewModel irrespective of the value coming from viewModel. in this case it is a binary value for a overlay. if viewModel changes to true, i show the overlay, if you click on close button from overlay, I have to close the overlay as well as update the value to false for viewModel, so that next time someone does toggle (`toggle=!toggle`) it will still open the overlay, otherwise doublw toggle is needed. close button on overlay triggers another close event in valueChanged

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no way to prevent a bindable property's change handler method from being called based on whether the custom element's own code is assigning the property or whether it's being assigned by external code or in response to user input. You will have to roll your own internal tracking mechanism.

Answer (score 0):

As Jeremy said, there's no way to prevent a bindable property's change handler from being called.  However, you could attach or trigger your code only with the form input using the `change.delegate` or `keyup.delegate` properties.  That would allow you to isolate your event code from the changes resulting from binding properties.

Here's a GistRun to demonstrate this:

https://gist.run/?id=11cd1e90dd912f07a60afaedb9c2613b